# jQuery Select2: Put selected options to other container

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any way to put selected options to other container?

Like on attached picture:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but how? Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post the code you've written so far.

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything yet. I just saw examples and read whole documentation to see if it is even possible. Only my quess has been to use events to copy selected options, and hide originals

Comment: Could you guide me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [JSFiddle (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/2nm3d/1/). When you select one option from the `#source` it is moved to `#target` (the default option with value zero is not moved in this example):

```
$(document).on('change', '#source', function() {
    $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if ($option.val()) {
        $option.detach();
        $option.appendTo('#target');

        //select2 adjustments
        $('#source').select2('val', '0');
        $('#target').select2();
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, but I really need to use jQuery-select2 plugin.

Comment: It should work with jQuery-select2, maybe with some adjustments (see my edit).

Comment: Could you present it on jsfiddle? :) Thanks for guiding

Comment: I will test it in home and give it a try :)

Comment: @Raidri that solution was great. Do u know how to force user to select at least 2 items in select2? Using parsley

Comment: I have been trying to implement on here but not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702152/jquery-select2-ajax-search-display-selected-results-in-another-div