# jquery-select2 ajax search display tags in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2-4

I would like to display the selected results in another div and not in the input box.

```js
function formatRepo (repo) {
      if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

      var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'></div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
          "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

      if (repo.description) {
        markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";
      }

      markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
        //"<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
        //"<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
       // "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div></div>";

      return markup;
 }

 function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
 }
     
     $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
       ajax: {
         url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
         dataType: 'json',
         delay: 250,
         data: function (params) {
           return {
             q: params.term, // search term
             page: params.page
           };
         },
         processResults: function (data, params) {
           // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
           // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
           // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
           // scrolling can be used
           params.page = params.page || 1;
              
              var jsonD = [{"error":false,"message":"","data":[{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"16323","GROUP_NAME":"AARHUS UNITED UK LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"44276","GROUP_NAME":"AMNESTY INTERNATIONAL UNITED KINGDOM_950138123"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40612","GROUP_NAME":"BAIN & COMPANY INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925001385"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3026","GROUP_NAME":"BECKMAN COULTER UNITED KINGDOM LTD_900028226"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40989","GROUP_NAME":"BOEING  UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_925001540"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43804","GROUP_NAME":"CONTITECH UNITED KINGDOM_925002897"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40454","GROUP_NAME":"CPM UNITED KINGDON LIMITED_925001355"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2316","GROUP_NAME":"CSM (UNITED KINGDOM) LTD_925000567"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2310","GROUP_NAME":"CUNNINGHAM LINDSEY UNITED KINGDOM_900002099"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"33735","GROUP_NAME":"EMBASSEY OF THE UNITED ARAB EMIRATES (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3132","GROUP_NAME":"EUROMEDIC UNITED KINGDOM  LTD_911460356"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3379","GROUP_NAME":"MCKINSEY & CO INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925000105"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13699","GROUP_NAME":"OXFORD UNITED FOOTBALL CLUB LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4584","GROUP_NAME":"PUMA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950005472"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3267","GROUP_NAME":"ROYAL UNITED HOSPITAL BATH - CATALIST_900223059"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"1436","GROUP_NAME":"S. & L. UNITED STORAGE SYSTEMS LTD_950031834"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17550","GROUP_NAME":"SER SOLUTIONS UNITED KINGDOM LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17630","GROUP_NAME":"SGS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_925000665"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"42205","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LIMITED_925002404"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40001","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LLP_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2549","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LTD_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2548","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGRI PRODUCTS  LIMITED - GPRS_900182496"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13327","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED ARAB EMIRATES EMBASSY (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4461","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA GROUP LTD_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3842","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA PLC - GPRS_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24535","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CARPETS LTD_910766502"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"41498","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CAST BAR (UK) LTD_950105891"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43894","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS LIMITED_925003162"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"723","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS_910115981"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40800","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DRUG PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY_925001555"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"113","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED LINCOLNSHIRE HOSPITALS CATALIST_900219353"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2547","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED RESPONSE - CATALIST_900254800"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24366","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED STATES EMBASSY_911415962"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2546","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED THERAPEUTICS EUROPE LTD_911232907"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"112","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITIES GROUP PLC_925000155"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40803","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITY GROUP PLC - M2M_925000941"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3841","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED WELSH HOUSING ASSOC. - CATALIST_900275753"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3176","GROUP_NAME":"UNITEDHEALTH UK LTD_911169045"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4454","GROUP_NAME":"VANDERLANDE INDUSTRIES UNITED KINGDOM LT_911405044"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"687","GROUP_NAME":"WMF UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_910383186"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2506","GROUP_NAME":"WPS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_910465482"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40186","GROUP_NAME":"YOKOGAWA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950099226"}],"dbdataCount":null}];
console.log(data);
              var dbData = [];
           for(i=0;i<jsonD[0].data.length;i++){
            dbData[i] = {id: jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME_ID, full_name:jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME};
           }
              console.log(jsonD);
           return {
             results: dbData,
             pagination: {
               more: (params.page * 30) < dbData.length
             }
           };
         },
         cache: true
       },
       multiple: true,
       escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
       minimumInputLength: 1,
       templateResult: formatRepo,
       templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
     }).on('change', function() {
     var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
     var $container = $(this).siblings('.js-example-tags-container');

     var $list = $('<ul>');
     $selected.each(function(k, v) {
       var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
       $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
         .off('click.select2-copy')
         .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
           var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
           $opt.attr('selected', false);
           $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
         }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
       $list.append($li);
     });
     $container.html('').append($list);
   }).trigger('change');
```

```css
function formatRepo (repo) {
      if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

      var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'></div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
          "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

      if (repo.description) {
        markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";
      }

      markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
        //"<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
        //"<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
       // "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div></div>";

      return markup;
 }

 function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
 }
     
     $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
       ajax: {
         url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
         dataType: 'json',
         delay: 250,
         data: function (params) {
           return {
             q: params.term, // search term
             page: params.page
           };
         },
         processResults: function (data, params) {
           // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
           // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
           // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
           // scrolling can be used
           params.page = params.page || 1;
              
              var jsonD = [{"error":false,"message":"","data":[{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"16323","GROUP_NAME":"AARHUS UNITED UK LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"44276","GROUP_NAME":"AMNESTY INTERNATIONAL UNITED KINGDOM_950138123"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40612","GROUP_NAME":"BAIN & COMPANY INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925001385"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3026","GROUP_NAME":"BECKMAN COULTER UNITED KINGDOM LTD_900028226"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40989","GROUP_NAME":"BOEING  UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_925001540"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43804","GROUP_NAME":"CONTITECH UNITED KINGDOM_925002897"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40454","GROUP_NAME":"CPM UNITED KINGDON LIMITED_925001355"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2316","GROUP_NAME":"CSM (UNITED KINGDOM) LTD_925000567"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2310","GROUP_NAME":"CUNNINGHAM LINDSEY UNITED KINGDOM_900002099"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"33735","GROUP_NAME":"EMBASSEY OF THE UNITED ARAB EMIRATES (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3132","GROUP_NAME":"EUROMEDIC UNITED KINGDOM  LTD_911460356"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3379","GROUP_NAME":"MCKINSEY & CO INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925000105"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13699","GROUP_NAME":"OXFORD UNITED FOOTBALL CLUB LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4584","GROUP_NAME":"PUMA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950005472"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3267","GROUP_NAME":"ROYAL UNITED HOSPITAL BATH - CATALIST_900223059"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"1436","GROUP_NAME":"S. & L. UNITED STORAGE SYSTEMS LTD_950031834"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17550","GROUP_NAME":"SER SOLUTIONS UNITED KINGDOM LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17630","GROUP_NAME":"SGS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_925000665"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"42205","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LIMITED_925002404"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40001","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LLP_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2549","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LTD_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2548","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGRI PRODUCTS  LIMITED - GPRS_900182496"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13327","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED ARAB EMIRATES EMBASSY (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4461","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA GROUP LTD_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3842","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA PLC - GPRS_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24535","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CARPETS LTD_910766502"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"41498","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CAST BAR (UK) LTD_950105891"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43894","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS LIMITED_925003162"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"723","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS_910115981"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40800","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DRUG PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY_925001555"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"113","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED LINCOLNSHIRE HOSPITALS CATALIST_900219353"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2547","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED RESPONSE - CATALIST_900254800"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24366","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED STATES EMBASSY_911415962"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2546","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED THERAPEUTICS EUROPE LTD_911232907"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"112","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITIES GROUP PLC_925000155"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40803","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITY GROUP PLC - M2M_925000941"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3841","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED WELSH HOUSING ASSOC. - CATALIST_900275753"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3176","GROUP_NAME":"UNITEDHEALTH UK LTD_911169045"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4454","GROUP_NAME":"VANDERLANDE INDUSTRIES UNITED KINGDOM LT_911405044"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"687","GROUP_NAME":"WMF UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_910383186"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2506","GROUP_NAME":"WPS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_910465482"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40186","GROUP_NAME":"YOKOGAWA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950099226"}],"dbdataCount":null}];
console.log(data);
              var dbData = [];
           for(i=0;i<jsonD[0].data.length;i++){
            dbData[i] = {id: jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME_ID, full_name:jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME};
           }
              console.log(jsonD);
           return {
             results: dbData,
             pagination: {
               more: (params.page * 30) < dbData.length
             }
           };
         },
         cache: true
       },
       multiple: true,
       escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
       minimumInputLength: 1,
       templateResult: formatRepo,
       templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
     }).on('change', function() {
     var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
     var $container = $(this).siblings('.js-example-tags-container');

     console.log($selected);
     var $list = $('<ul>');
     $selected.each(function(k, v) {
       var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
       $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
         .off('click.select2-copy')
         .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
           var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
           $opt.attr('selected', false);
           $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
         }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
       $list.append($li);
     });
     $container.html('').append($list);
   }).trigger('change');;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="border-radius">
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
   <fieldset class="border-radius white-bg">
   <legend class="border-radius">Search Customer/s</legend>
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <select class="js-example-data-ajax" style="width:100%">
       
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <button id="search_customers" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
              <div class="js-example-tags-container">
       
      </div>
 
   </fieldset>
   
  </div>
  <!-- //.span6 -->

  <div class="col-md-6 ">
   <fieldset class="border-radius white-bg">
   <legend class="border-radius">Search Customer/s</legend>
    <div class="col-md-10">
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
              
              <div>display select in list here</div>
 
   </fieldset>
   
  </div>
  <!-- //.span6 -->
 </div>
 <!-- //.row-fluid -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem I found was with the container class.

```
$(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
          ajax: {
            //url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
            url: "<?=BASE_URL ?>api/corporate-performance-dashboard/get-customers",
            dataType: 'json',
            type : 'POST',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
              return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
              // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
              // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
              // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
              // scrolling can be used
              var dbData = [];
              if(data.data != null){
                  for(i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
                      dbData[i] = {id: data.data[i].GROUP_NAME_ID,full_name:data.data[i].GROUP_NAME, text:data.data[i].GROUP_NAME };
                  }
              }

              params.page = params.page || 1;

              return {
                results: dbData,
                pagination: {
                  more: (params.page * 30) < dbData.length
                }
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          multiple: true,
          tags: true,
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
          minimumInputLength: 3,
         templateResult: formatRepo,
          templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
    }).on('change', function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var $container = $('.js-example-tags-container');

        var $list = $('<ul>');
        $selected.each(function(k, v) {
            var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
            $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
                .off('click.select2-copy')
                .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
                    var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
                     $opt.attr('selected', false);
                    $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
            }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
            $list.append($li);
        });
        $container.html('').append($list);
    }).trigger('change');
```